# (Volley) How to handle returning JsonObject after Post Method

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

I am sending object with Post method in Volley. My api returns such a data like in postman and it is what i want.

{
    "operationStatus": 3,
    "messages": [
        {
            "message": "Hata!"
        }
    ]
}

But I tried to get the such data my method in onResponse to handle. But it returns only 200.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("LOG_RESPONSE", response);
                Toast.makeText(DetailAirdrop.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Is there any way to get get jsonObject after post method in volley?

---

## Solved

**Solution:**

```
JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, url,
                jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(DetailAirdrop.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
```

Comment: have u overrided parsenetworkresponse?

Comment: Please don't show the solution as part of the question. If your problem was solved by an answer someone else posted, you should accept this answer. If you found out how to fix the problem and want to share this, please write an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"LINK", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            JSONObject mJsonObject;

            try {
                mJsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

               Toast.makeText(DetailAirdrop.this, 
               mJsonObject.getString("operationStatus") Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                JSONArray mJsonArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("messages");
                int a = mJsonArray.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

                    JSONObject jo = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

             Toast.makeText(DetailAirdrop.this, 
           mModel.setID(jo.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Crash", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    }));
```

it will work i tested 
and if it work tic my ansewer TY :)